# LINQ query to parse content from XML to class

Tags: c#, linq

I have an xml from which I am trying to extract some information through LINQ query.
The format of the xml file looks like the following:

```
<TopNode>
  <Sample name="Tom" id="0" batch="1">
    <Sequences>
      <NextItem id="10">Stand1 &gt;</NextItem>
      <PreviousItem id="9">Stand2 &gt;</PreviousItem>
    </Sequences>
  </Sample>
  <Sample name="Hill" id="1" batch="1">
    <Sequences>
      <NextItem id="1">Stand1 &gt;</NextItem>
      <NextItem id="2">Stand3 &gt;</NextItem>
      <PreviousItem id="3">Stand4 &gt;</PreviousItem>
    </Sequences>
  </Sample>
.
.
.
</TopNode>
```

I have to get a list of attributes of both `NextItem` and `PreviousItem` from the query. For this, I defined a class to get my results.

```
public class Extract
{
public string name 
{
get;
set;
}
public int _id
{
get;
set;
}
}
```

LINQ Query (foreach Sample node, get the PreviousItem and NextItem content in class object):

```
var EnumerableContent = from item in XElement.Load("file.xml").Elements("NextItem")
              select ???...
```

The problem is how do I pass the data to the class objects here in the above query for each Sample node. 
.
Secondly, the above will only get me NextItem nodes. How do I write the query for both NextItem and PreviousItem?

**EDIT**
On the whole, I have to get an IEnumerable for each for each of the `Sequence` nodes, and then return the overall IEnumerable from thie query.

**EDIT2**
Assigning `key` here is giving me this error. Query below

```
var mapping = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
                          .Descendants("Sequences")
                          .Select(n => n.Descendants("PreviousItem")
                              .Union(n.Descendants("NextItem"))
                              .Select(n1 => new Extract { _id = (int)n1.Attribute("id"), Name = n1.Value })
                              ).ToDictionary<IEnumberable<Menu>, int>(key => key._id);//and further converting this dictionary to sorted dictionary (sorted accordign to keys)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("NextItem")
  .Union(xDoc.Descendants("PreviousItem"))
  .Select(n => new {ID = n.Attribute("id").Value, Name =n.Name, Value =n.Value });
```

**--EDIT--**

```
var result = XDocument.Load(....)
            .Descendants("Sequences")
            .Select(n=> n.Descendants("NextItem")
                 .Union(n.Descendants("PreviousItem"))
                 .Select(n2 => new { ID = n2.Attribute("id").Value, Name = n2.Name, Value = n2.Value })
            );
```

Comment: This will give me the IEnumerable for each of the NextItem, and PreviousItem in the xml. What I actually want is that, for each of the Sequence nodes, I should generate an enumberable  and then return an overall IEnumberable of the above. I hope I am abe to convey the problem. ;-/

Comment: @Cipher I updated the answer, I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but the reason I wrote an Extarct Class was that I wanted to convert the result into a dictionary afterwards i.e `.ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where `TValue` could be the Extract class's IEnumberable. In the above statement, I am not able to do `.Select(new Menu{ SeekPoint = (int)n1.Attribute("time"), ItemText = n1.Value })`

Comment: Actually, edited my question. See EDIT2 for going a bit further to the problem.

Comment: @Cipher then, don't convert it to Dict. just append a `ToList` and use as a list.

Comment: I need the key-Value pairs. That is why converting it to dictionary. I can conver the dictionary to sorted afterwards but the problem is that there is some problem is generating this dictionary also. I am getting this error: Error: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EGAPP.Menu>' does not contain a definition for '_id' and no extension method '_id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EGAPP.Menu>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but you can easily take element/attribute value inside LINQ to XML `select` statement:

```
var EnumerableContent = from item in XElement.Load("file.xml").Elements("NextItem")
              select new Extract() { name = item.Value, _id = (int)item.Attribute("id") }
```

Comment: I am getting only `NextItem` elements, but I want to modify the query get the same thing for the `PreviousItem` nodes too. ;-/
The problem is that I want to get a separate IEnumerable of `PreviousItem` and `NextItem` for each of the `Sequence` nodes in xml, and return the overall IEnumberable

Answer (score 0):

hi i think this is what you expect.

```
List<XElement> lstXElements = new List<XElement>();
        lstXElements.AddRange(GetDescendants("NextItem"));
        lstXElements.AddRange(GetDescendants("PreviousItem"));

        List<Extract> lstExtract = new List<Extract>();

        foreach (XElement objElement in lstXElements)
        {
            Extract objExtract = new Extract();
            objExtract._id = Convert.ToInt32(objElement.Attribute("id").Value);
            objExtract.name = (objElement.Name).LocalName;
            lstExtract.Add(objExtract);
        }
List<XElement> GetDescendants(string strDescentName)
    {
        return ((XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"))
            .Descendants(strDescentName))
            ).ToList<XElement>();
    }
```